# Can I use a form tag inside PHP code

Tags: php, html, forms, button

I m trying to put a submit button inside a php code using form tag.
however, I can't click the button while running the code

the code will be like that:

```
<?php
    print("<form action='page.php' method='post'>
        <input type='hidden' name='CourseID' value='".$Array[0]."'> 
        // $Array[0] comes from a Query in php                                            
        <input type='submit' value='Edit' name='Edit' >
    </form>");
?>
```

Comment: write html add php for value  `value=<?php echo $Array[0] ?>`

Comment: sorry, but it didnt work

Answer (score 2):

You can write any html using php as below:

```
 <?php
        echo '<form action="page.php" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="CourseID" value="'.$Array[0].'"> 
            <input type="submit" value="Edit" name="Edit">
        </form>';
    ?>
```

Comment: @ArwaMoath "Doesn't work" - do you receive an error? does any elements of the form show?

Comment: $ArwaMoath: actually from me these code is working perfectly...dont know why its not woking for you.

Comment: I tried in another spot Dhara and it worked. but in the exact spat i want it to be its not!

Answer (score 1):

It didn't work for me either! The form would display but selection would not work for a dropdown although the submit button worked. I was writing a form in PHP for a short code for wordpress plugin. I had to write the code without echo, using closing and opening of PHP tags and mixing HTML and PHP that way. For example:

```
echo '<form action="page.php" method="post">
```

had to be written as:

```
?> <form action="page.php" method=post""><?php
```

It is tricky to write code this way but with perseverance and method to keep code readable it works.
Below is another example of inserting a HTML line of a form in PHP that shows how to use PHP variables inside ($term_name in our example below)

```
?>
        <option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($term_name); ?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($term_name); ?></option>
<?php
```